# Conditional Left Join w/ PowerQuery - Large Dataset

Tags: excel, left-join, powerquery

### Here's the PowerQuery problem

*(Static Application Security Testing) SAST Scanner --- gives ---> Vuln, Line #, File Path, etc.*

*Mapped Test Suite for Scanner --- gives ---> Function, Line Start, Line End, File Path, etc.*

I put all the data in Excel.

**Now I need to connect the 'Scanner' data w/ the 'Test Suite Map' data**

Example Tables of datasets:

---

**Scanner**

| Vuln Desc | Line # | File Path |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SQL Injection | 5 | \TestSuite\CWE89\sql_injection.cs |
| SQL Injection | 15 | \TestSuite\CWE89\sql_injection.cs |

---

**Map**

| Function | Line Start | Line End | File Path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bad_Function() | 1 | 10 | \TestSuite\CWE89\sql_injection.cs |
| Good_Function() | 11 | 20 | \TestSuite\CWE89\sql_injection.cs |

---

I'm using this process to analyze how many "Good" (False Positive) and "Bad" (True Positive) functions are being detected by the scanners.

I'm trying to do this with PowerQuery and using their "M" language.
I've tried to use some of the "M" language docs and also https://p3adaptive.com/2019/02/powerquerymagic-conditional-joins-using-table-selectrows/.

**However,** these are not working...results below.

1. Go into Power Query
2. Create a Custom Column for the 'Scanner' table

[image: Custom Column]

3. "M" Code as "Custom Column Formula"

```
    Table.SelectRows(Map, (map_ref)=> 
    ([#"Line #"]>=map_ref[Line Start] 
    and [#"Line #"]<=map_ref[Line End] and [File Path]=map_ref[File Path]))
```

[image: Power Query Code Example]

4. I expand the new column into the matched 'Map' columns

This works for the test set of data here

**Scanner (Left Joined w/Map)**

| Function | Line # | File Path | Scanner to Map.Function |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SQL Injection | 5 | \TestSuite\CWE89\sql_injection.cs | Bad_Function() |
| SQL Injection | 15 | \TestSuite\CWE89\sql_injection.cs | Good_Function() |

---

**The problem is that it doesn't work for my actual data**

Some thing to mention that I've already fixed:

- I already made sure the file paths will match up

### ***My Actual Tables (smaller dataset - that works)***

**VCG_juliet_test_results_csharp**

| Type Name | File Path | Line |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SQL Injection | C:\Users\User_Name\Documents\SAST Benchmarking\juliet_test_suite_1.3-csharp\src\testcases\CWE319_Cleartext_Tx_Sensitive_Info\CWE319_Cleartext_Tx_Sensitive_Info__NetClient_SqlConnection_05.cs | 321 |
| SQL Injection | C:\Users\User_Name\Documents\SAST Benchmarking\juliet_test_suite_1.3-csharp\src\testcases\CWE319_Cleartext_Tx_Sensitive_Info\CWE319_Cleartext_Tx_Sensitive_Info__NetClient_SqlConnection_06.cs | 117 |

**juliet_test_suite_csharp_map**

| filepath | type | line_start | line_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C:\Users\User_Name\Documents\SAST Benchmarking\juliet_test_suite_1.3-csharp\src\testcases\CWE319_Cleartext_Tx_Sensitive_Info\CWE319_Cleartext_Tx_Sensitive_Info__NetClient_SqlConnection_05.cs | secondary good | 255 | 334 |
| C:\Users\User_Name\Documents\SAST Benchmarking\juliet_test_suite_1.3-csharp\src\testcases\CWE319_Cleartext_Tx_Sensitive_Info\CWE319_Cleartext_Tx_Sensitive_Info__NetClient_SqlConnection_06.cs | secondary good | 94 | 130 |

As you can see, these functions should also match up.  The line numbers are in between the line numbers of the second table.  Therefore, the "Conditional Left Join" should work here.

(Using Add Column in Power Query)
**Custom Code to do Conditional Join***

```
Table.SelectRows(juliet_test_suite_csharp_map, (map_ref)=> ([Line]>=map_ref[line_start] 
    and [Line]<=map_ref[line_end] and [File Path]=map_ref[filepath]))
```

[image: Custom Column - Conditional Left Join]

**VCG_juliet_test_results_csharp (joined w/ test suite map)**

| Type Name | File Path | Line | Juliet Mapping.filepath | Juliet Mapping.type | Juliet Mapping.line_start | Juliet Mapping.line_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SQL Injection | C:\Users\User_Name\Documents\SAST Benchmarking\juliet_test_suite_1.3-csharp\src\testcases\CWE319_Cleartext_Tx_Sensitive_Info\CWE319_Cleartext_Tx_Sensitive_Info__NetClient_SqlConnection_05.cs | 321 | C:\Users\User_Name\Documents\SAST Benchmarking\juliet_test_suite_1.3-csharp\src\testcases\CWE319_Cleartext_Tx_Sensitive_Info\CWE319_Cleartext_Tx_Sensitive_Info__NetClient_SqlConnection_05.cs | secondary good | 255 | 334 |
| SQL Injection | C:\Users\User_Name\Documents\SAST Benchmarking\juliet_test_suite_1.3-csharp\src\testcases\CWE319_Cleartext_Tx_Sensitive_Info\CWE319_Cleartext_Tx_Sensitive_Info__NetClient_SqlConnection_06.cs | 117 | C:\Users\User_Name\Documents\SAST Benchmarking\juliet_test_suite_1.3-csharp\src\testcases\CWE319_Cleartext_Tx_Sensitive_Info\CWE319_Cleartext_Tx_Sensitive_Info__NetClient_SqlConnection_06.cs | secondary good | 94 | 130 |

---

***It does work here, but when we do it on a larger dataset w/ the same format we get this.***

[image: all null values]

Some extra info:

- the data set is around 216,000 rows

Above picture:

- When I expand the column I get all null values
- When I close and load, it loads about 3 rows a second.  There are **200,000** rows so that would take 18.5 hours!! (my math might be off there)

**Conclusion**

- My conditional left join works on smaller datasets w/ the same formatting and same add column formula
- In Power Query after expanding the column, I'm left with all null values.  Although, closing and loading the query causes it to load at super slow speeds
- The problem might be the large dataset, and maybe Power Query isn't made for this.  I might have to write a manual program for this larger dataset

Would like to here from people more versed in Power Query and solving these types of problems.  If there is anymore info I can give you about how I'm doing feel free to ask, and I can edit my question.

Comment: I'm fixing this post rn.  It doesn't show right on post, but in review it looks fine.